# Why do I need a second for loop w/ append to make this list?

Tags: python, list

I'm pulling numbers from a file using regular expressions. When trying to print nums, it only gives me an empty list.

```
import re
fh = open('sample.txt')

for line in fh:
    nums = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
print(nums)
```

`print(nums)` prints an empty list. Why? I had to create a second for loop and append to a different list to get the numbers.

```
import re 
fh = open('sample.txt')
numbers = []

for line in fh:
    nums = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    for num in nums:
        num = int(num)
        numbers.append(num)
print(numbers)
```

Why does `print(numbers)` return the numbers from the file, and `print(nums)` not?

sample.txt pulls data from: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_483474.txt

Comment: I'm guessing that the last line didn't have any matches, and since your first loop was just overwriting `nums` on each iteration, the result was that last empty line.

Comment: Try move `print(nums)` inside the for loop and see if it prints your numbers.

Comment: You are overwriting the list in each iteration and your last last line the file is 'The End' which doesn't have any numbers in it. So final output is empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause u print last match only...
Try with this:

```
import re
fh = open('sample.txt')

for line in fh:
    nums = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    print(nums)
```